# TemplateDoesNotExist PythonAnywhere Django error

Tags: python, django, templates, pythonanywhere

TemplateDoesNotExist

Trying to launch my first web app on PA and things just aren't working when going from local to PA for some reason.

My Template path is settings.py is

```
 import os

 BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
     'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_PATH],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
 },

 ]
```

and my app is included in the installed_apps section of settings.py. How do I fix this?

TemplateDoesNotExist at /Kappa/

Kappa/index.html

Request Method: GET Request URL: http://ktruong88.pythonanywhere.com/Kappa/ Django Version: 1.8.4 Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist Exception Value:

Kappa/index.html

> ```
> Exception Location: /home/KTruong88/.virtualenvs/Kappa/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py
> ```
>
> in get_template, line 46 Python Executable: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
>   Python Version: 3.4.0 Python Path:
>
> ```
> ['/var/www', '.', '', '/var/www', '/home/KTruong88/.virtualenvs/Kappa/lib/python3.4',
> ```
>
> '/home/KTruong88/.virtualenvs/Kappa/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>   '/home/KTruong88/.virtualenvs/Kappa/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
>   '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>   '/home/KTruong88/.virtualenvs/Kappa/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
>   '/home/KTruong88/Kappa_Ranks/']

Comment: Try `['TEMPLATE_PATH']`

Comment: Still getting the same error message with that.

Comment: What if you remove the the whole `TEMPLATES` list part and use this instead `TEMPLATE_DIRS = (  TEMPLATE_PATH+"/templates" ,)` ?

Comment: What is the location of the `Kappa/index.html` which is not being found?

Comment: Not sure how, but the problem got fixed. I think I edited the wsgi file to put import django
django.setup()

 at the top instead of the middle. Only problem is it shows another error message now. I think I'll post another question right now.